# PayPal pass through variables using REST API SDK for PHP

Tags: php, paypal

I am using the PHP SDK for PayPal and am successfully creating payments and return messages, although I can't figure out from the [documentation](http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/docs/namespace-PayPal.Api.html) how to reliably pass through my own vars that will be passed back to me in the $_GET string to the response URL.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Please post your code.

Answer (score 1):

When `payment_method` is set to `paypal`, you can pass `custom` field in the `transaction` object. This field can hold 256 characters and you should be able to get it in $_GET string.

Comment: Hi thanks so much for your help. I've set up a new transaction object and have added the following:

`$transaction->setCustom('Stuff to pass to return URL')`

although no luck sadly. Ideally there would be some kind of custom metadata array that could contain key value pairs for example and it outputs in the json response object. Seems that paypal limit the fields that can be passed, I need to pass through a few. Hmm.

Appreciate your continued input if you are able to. Thanks!

Comment: I've also tried

`$payerInfo = new PayerInfo();`
`$payerInfo->setExternalRememberMeId($user);`

and tried passing that in to the `Payer()` object like so `$payer->setPayerInfo($payerInfo);` but that errors out on connection with PayPal.

I did this referring to these pages (http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/docs/class-PayPal.Api.PayerInfo.html) and (http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/docs/class-PayPal.Api.Payer.html)